# Calculate a variable depending on another variables by row

Tags: r

I want to calculate a variable "value", which is depending on "a" and "b":

> type "A" value = (sum(a_A1) - mean(a_A))/sd(a_A) + (sum(b_A1) - mean(b_A))/sd(b_A))/2
>
> type "B" value = (sum(a_B1) - mean(a_B))/sd(a_B) + (sum(b_B1) - mean(b_B))/sd(b_B))/2
>
> type "C" value =
> ....

```
set.seed(101)

type <- c("A","B","A","A","C","B", "C", "World")
a <- abs(rnorm(8) * 5)
b <- abs(rnorm(8) * 5)
df <- data.frame(type,a,b)
```

I have try like this:

```
df <- transform(df, value = ave(df$a, df$b, df$type, 
                    FUN = function(a,b) ((sum(a)-mean(a))/sd(a) +(sum(b)-mean(b)/sd(b))/2))
```

but it doesn't work.

So any one can tell how I calculate "value".

Comment: Please edit your question to add `set.seed` and expected output

Comment: this is typically a use for `switch` isn't it ?

Comment: Made easy with `dplyr`... i.e. `library(dplyr); df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(value = ((sum(a)-mean(a))/sd(a) +(sum(b)-mean(b)/sd(b))/2))`

Comment: Thanks for reply and edit(I have no ideal to deal with it).With your code, "value" is all the same value. But "sum(a)" might be like sum(a1), sum(a2)...

Comment: what do you mean sum(a1)? a1 is one value rights?

Comment: Or the a in sum(a) is a single value, a in mean(a) is a variable. It's different.

Comment: I use formula in excel like this: 
=((B2-average(B$2:b$9)/sd(B$2:B$9))+(C2-average(C$2:C$9)/sd(C$2:C$9)))/2
and drag to all rows

Comment: Then replace the first sum with simply `a` (`b` for the second one)

Comment: @Sotos Thanks, it might work.

Answer (score 1):

After the comments Sotos and your clarification, you might need:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(type) %>% 
 mutate(value = ((a-mean(a))/sd(a) +(b-mean(b)/sd(b))/2))
```

Comment: thanks a lot. It works. But when I use it on my database, the result from R still has some difference with the one from excel. I still have no clue why it happens.

Comment: Your formula in Excel doesn't subselect for each type (A, B, ..) which doesn't agree with the original question, so am a bit confused.Did you really want to use mean and sd of values of 'a' & 'b' for all type As and then apply the formula for each row, or did you want to use the mean and sd for all values of 'a' regardless of type? To achieve the first you'd have to use sumif or similar plus several columns in Excel. Thanks.

Comment: I have sub-selected different type into different tables and calculate them separately(yep,it looks so dumm, that's why I try in R).
the mean and sd is applied for the whole a column and b column by the same type and calculated in each row.

Comment: And the more weird it is, the difference between R result and excel result is only on a few rows

Comment: Not having access to your original (presumably) large dataset, it is difficult to pin point the reason for the difference. By chance would you be able to run the analysisin Excel for the 8 data points generated by your original code with the random data (with seed of 101) and looking to see if the intermediate values correspond.

Comment: You can use `aggregate(cbind(a,b) ~ type, data=df, FUN = function(x) c(mn=mean(x),sd=sd(x)))` to get the mean and sd for each variable by type in R. Also `df %>% group_by(type) %>% mutate(a_mn=mean(a), a_sd=sd(a), b_mn=mean(b), b_sd=sd(b))` in `dplyr`. Good luck.

Comment: the result of the 8 rows example is the same between R and excel. So I think the problem is on the process of R importing. Thanks anyway!!